Is merge in Byte Pair encoding (BPE) optimal?
Let a string be s = "aeeefeekeelaeoae",
Vocab: {a, e, f, k, l, o} (set of characters in s)
Lets say I performed Byte Pair Encoding (BPE) on s and I want number of merges to be 2 such that my final vocab size becomes 8. "ee" gets merged first because it occurs the most. However, how to decide which indices to merge, (s[2] + s[3]) or (s[3] + s[4])?
if we were to merge s[2] + s[3], then we will get a less compressed string as compared to when we merge s[3] + s[4]. Because after "ee", we have "ae" of higher occurrences.
case 1 (merge s[2] and s[3]):
let "ee" be Z
s becomes "aZefZkZlaeoae"
"ae" occurs the most. Let "ae" be X then s becomes "aZefZkZlXoX"
case 2 (merge s[3] and s[4]):
let "ee" be Z
s becomes "aeZfZkZlaeoae"
"ae" occurs the most. Let "ae" be X then s becomes "XZfZkZlXoX"
As you can see after two merges, case 2 gives optimal solution as string length becomes 10 as compared to case 1 where string length becomes 11

You might want to clarify the question a bit more. I presume by "BPE" you mean "byte pair encoding"?

Yes @MartinWunderlich
